# Script is running but don't know where it is stuck

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my script where I have used nested loops, but when I was trying to print values in the inner loop, it's not printing anything.
It's not entering into the first loop.

Can you explain what's going wrong?

```
CURR_DIR=`dirname $0`
SCRIPT_DIR=`pwd`
echo "Current Directory: $CURR_DIR"
source ${CURR_DIR}/db.conf
mysql --batch --raw -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $MYDB \
      -e'SELECT dc_id,dc_name from `dc_mast`' |
awk '{print $1 "," $2 "\n"}'>${CURR_DIR}/datac.txt
sed -i -e "1d" ${CURR_DIR}/datac.txt
sed -i -e '/^$/d' ${CURR_DIR}/datac.txt
echo "outer first loop"
while IFS="," read dc_id dc_name
do
  echo ${dc_id} 
  echo "inner first loop" ${dc_id}
  mysql --batch --raw -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $MYDB \
        -e'SELECT distinct c.cl_id as cl_id,c.cl_dns as cl_dns
             FROM cso_crm.cluster_mast c
             JOIN cso_crm.env_detail e on e.cl_id=c.cl_id
             JOIN cso_crm.env_mast m on m.env_id=e.env_id
            WHERE m.dc_id='${dc_id}' and m.service_id='1' and e.app_id='2'' |
  awk '{print $1 "," $2 "\n"}' > ${CURR_DIR}/cl.txt

  sed -i -e "1d" ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt
  sed -i -e '/^$/d' ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt

  while IFS="," read cl_id cl_dns
  do
    echo "inner second loop" ${cl_id}
    mysql --batch --raw -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $MYDB \
          -e'select c.cust_name as customer
               from cluster_mast m
               join env_detail d on m.cl_id =d.cl_id
               join env_mast e on d.env_id = e.env_id
               join cust_mast c on e.cust_id = c.cust_id
              where m.cl_id='${cl_id}' and e.status=1' |
    awk '{print $1 "\n"}'> ${CURR_DIR}/cname.txt
    sed -i -e "1d" ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt
    sed -i -e '/^$/d' ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt

    while IFS="," read customer
    do
      echo "https://"${cl_dns}"/"${cust_name} $'\n' > ${CURR_DIR}/xxx_url.txt
    done
    rm cname.txt
  done
  rm c1.txt
done
```

Comment: your script has some errors in it. for example you are creating a flie named **cl.txt** and then try to read a file named **c1.txt**. other than that only commands with mysql in them can be wrong (I don't know).

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: thank you for your comment . Now I understand what was the problem. I haven't add file name in the end.

Comment: Here is a tip:  rather than hard-code the same file name over and over, create a variable at the top of the script and use that everywhere, e.g. `filename="c1.txt"`.  That way you reduce the number of typos, and if you need to change the filename at any time (like adding a directory name for it) it only has to be done in one place.

Comment: Why its not printing a output in xxx.txt line  by line. Its printing only last line.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script after `#!/bin/bash` add:

```
export 'PS4=\e[1;34m+ ${FUNCNAME:-main}@\e[1;36m${BASH_SOURCE}: \e[0;32m${LINENO}->  \e[0m'
```

It will display more detailed debug info.

Then you just need to run:
`bash -x <my_script>.sh`

Comment: Do you have any idea how to print output in xxx.txt line by line?

Comment: `bash -x <my_script>.sh &> xxx.txt` or `bash -x <my_script>.sh | tee xxx.txt`

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I had an obscure issue in my bash script and this really helped me debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try adding:

```
set -o xtrace
```

as the first line of your program. Bash will then echo each command as it executes.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is stuck in the `read` waiting for you to type something (apparently, a `cl_id` and a `cl_dns`).

You didn't provide I/O redirection to the loop.  You might have meant to add `< ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt` after the `done` to provide input to the `read`.

Note that the quotes in your `mysql` scripts aren't doing what you think.  You have (once reformatted for readability):

```
mysql --batch --raw -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $MYDB \
      -e'SELECT distinct c.cl_id as cl_id,c.cl_dns as cl_dns
           FROM cso_crm.cluster_mast c
           JOIN cso_crm.env_detail e on e.cl_id=c.cl_id
           JOIN cso_crm.env_mast m on m.env_id=e.env_id
          WHERE m.dc_id='${dc_id}' and m.service_id='1' and e.app_id='2'' |
```

The whole expression is enclosed in single quotes, so the single quotes in the 'middle' simply suppress single-quoting.  The `mysql` command does not see any of the single quotes.  It is equivalent to writing:

```
mysql --batch --raw -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $MYDB \
      -e'SELECT distinct c.cl_id as cl_id,c.cl_dns as cl_dns
           FROM cso_crm.cluster_mast c
           JOIN cso_crm.env_detail e on e.cl_id=c.cl_id
           JOIN cso_crm.env_mast m on m.env_id=e.env_id
          WHERE m.dc_id='${dc_id}' and m.service_id=1 and e.app_id=2' |
```

If the `service_id` and `app_id` need to be string comparisons, you probably need:

```
mysql --batch --raw -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS -h $DB_HOST $MYDB \
      -e"SELECT distinct c.cl_id as cl_id,c.cl_dns as cl_dns
           FROM cso_crm.cluster_mast c
           JOIN cso_crm.env_detail e on e.cl_id=c.cl_id
           JOIN cso_crm.env_mast m on m.env_id=e.env_id
          WHERE m.dc_id=${dc_id} and m.service_id='1' and e.app_id='2'" |
```

using double quotes around the whole statement.  If the `dc_id` should be a string too, you can add single quotes around that (and this time `mysql` will see the single quotes).

In your outer loop, you have:

```
awk '{print $1 "\n"}' >${CURR_DIR}/cname.txt
sed -i -e "1d" ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt
sed -i -e '/^$/d' ${CURR_DIR}/c1.txt
```

You edited `c1.txt` before you entered the loop; it seems silly to edit it again.  You probably intended to write `c1.txt`.

Also, `sed` can do multiple edits in one run:

```
sed -i -e "1d" -e '/^$/d' ${CURR_DIR}/cname.txt
```

And you could put the output of `awk` through `sed`:

```
awk '{print $1 "\n"}' |
sed -e "1d" -e '/^$/d' > ${CURR_DIR}/cname.txt
```

But you could have `awk` do all the editing in the first place:

```
awk 'NR==1{next} /^$/{next} {print $1 "\n"}' > ${CURR_DIR}/cname.txt
```

This commentary applies to the first `awk`, `sed`, `sed` sequence too.

And do note what [cdarke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736308/cdarke) said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420749/script-is-running-but-dont-know-where-it-is-stuck/30426973#comment48929993_30420749) about using variables to hold a file name.  If you're going to mention a file name more than once, use a variable to hold it.  That means you'll almost always have a variable holding each filename.